# facebook messanger -wit.ai integration -Chatbot -heroku deployed

Tags: node.js, heroku, bots, facebook-messenger, wit.ai

I am working towards a chatbot,with wit.ai and facebook messanger as the interface for it,The integrating process went error less and the curl -H gave 
{success:true},but the bot does not respond if messaged,I looked all over it,may i know is it because of heroku for which this behaviour is seen,or the deployment platform does not matter at all,what can be the area or part that i may be missing out?

List of things i have already done:

- 1 create a story over wit.ai
- 2 a simple nodejs server code printing ("this is a bot").
- 3 after properly executing,wrote the whole bot.
- 4 deployed it to heroku
- 5 in Facebook Developer section,created apps for messanger.
- 6 setup webhook,after creating a verify_token,it shows "complete"
- 7 generate page token and put verify_token and page_access_token in heroku dashboard's "config vars"
- 8 subscribe the page
- 9 trigger it using curl and chat with the bot;**

  - *error: bot does not respond in the page
  - url/webhook -> bad request*

Can anyone give me some suggestions regarding this

Answer (score 1):

I find it highly unlikely that there is a heroku problem. Did you try chatting with the bot without using witai? Also type `heroku logs` on terminal to see if there are some errors in your application. I used heroku to deploy my chatbot, and it works really well since you can find all the errors in the logs. I am not well versed with witai, but since it is just calling the bot, heroku shouldn't be the one causing the error

Comment: yes,heroku logs throws an app crashed error,i have mentioned the two errors above,when you type your url/webhook->bad request,since the app is crashing,and i find no reasons for it to fail each time.